# Install Opera on 64-bit

Tags: installation, 64-bit, opera

I tried to follow the instructions on the [opera page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser), but it didn't work. I was assuming the base install should be the same for 64-bit, but it doesn't look so. After executing

```
wget -qO - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

successfully

```
sudo apt-get install opera
```

says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package opera is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'opera' has no installation candidate
```

Below on the page I see

```
A 64 bit Linux version is available, you should get it automatically either from the repositories or from Opera
```

I haven't tried to download it manually, since I prefer to get it from a repo. It it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deb you are installing is from opera.com and the wiki you refer to is about opera 10 the latest stable build of opera is 11.01 which you can download from [opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/).

All you need to do is select the Ubuntu and deb and download and install. When installation is completed opera's own repository will be added and you will receive updates from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, the repo [contains](http://deb.opera.com/opera/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) the latest version, 11.01.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I'm very new to apt-get. Do you claim it is there? How did you find it out? What command should I run?

Comment: @maaartinus: The opera_...deb package [exists](http://deb.opera.com/opera/pool/non-free/o/opera/) and is reffered by [Packages](http://deb.opera.com/opera/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages).

Comment: Me stupid.... now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your apt cache by issuing:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I had done it, but I forgot to mention it in my question.